# How can I stop problems with the screen when I change the font size to "Large"?

Tags: screen, fonts

When I change my phone font to "Large", the screen layout is messed up. The screenshots how that the right margin is increased. The left screenshot shows the normal margins. The right screenshot shows how the Google Now field, the camera and the Settings icon are bumped to the left. (I drew the blue arrows in a paint program.)

If I change the font to "Normal", then back to "Large", the increased margin does not appear right away. But, when I have the font setting on "Large" and then exit a phone call or message or an app, the margin gets increased.

Phone/app details:

Phone: Moto E 2nd generation with 4G LTE
Android version 5.1

Added Apps:

iNaturalist, 
Audubon Birds, 
Clipboard History, 
eBird, 
Excel, 
GPS Coordinates, 
Overdrive, 
Simplenote, 
Yahoo Mail, 
Zinio

Along with the ones that came with the phone:
Google Calendar, Camera, Chrome, etc.

No alternate launcher.
Multiple windows is not enabled.

[image]

Comment: What is your device, the OS version, and, especially, are you using a 3rd party launcher like Nova? Also provide whether you have multiple windows or gestures enabled, since they can rely on the borders or corners of your home screen.

Comment: Not repro on Nexus 5, Android 6.0.1, stock Launcher, so I think it could be something dependent. Please include the info asked by wbogacz to help all of us analyzing the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for replying to my posted question. I also posted to How To Geek. Someone there suggested that it is a bug that should be reported to the Google Android Issues forums, which I did. The result was that it was marked as being "obsolete" with no explanation. I am wondering if it is because Android will have a new operating system version (?). I think it is called Marshmallow (?). My phone runs on the older operating system.  I don't fully understand all of the Android systems because I am new to smartphones. But, for now, I will keep my phone font on "Normal".